# SQL Server : remove trailing 0's after decimal point. nvarchar datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, leading-zero

I am writing a SQL query returning gross pay from two separate tables. The amounts in both tables are of `nvarchar` datatype. In one table I have '150.0000' and on the other I have '150' is there any way to remove the trailing 0's? Here is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.EEid,
    s.Gross AS 'S Gross',
    pr.EEid,
    pr.Gross AS 'PR Gross'
FROM 
    starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN 
    payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
ORDER BY 
    s.EEid
```

Results from query

[image: Results from query above]

I have tried this line of code to trim the leading 0's but it returns '15.' it removes all 0's.

Here is the code

```
REPLACE(ltrim(REPLACE(s.Gross,'0','')), ' ', '0') AS 'S Gross'
```

Result from this line of code

[image: Results from REPLACE]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some sample data and expected results who be helpful @Mark

Comment: Why are you storing it as `nvarchar`?

Comment: Store your numerical data as a numerical datatype (`decimal`/`numeric`, `int`, `float`/`real`, etc) and this problem solves itself; numerical datatypes don't display leading 0's. The problem is your choice of datatype, not string value of the data.

Comment: If you are sure the values are always numeric, you could `cast` it to a `decimal` with no decimals -- `cast(yourfield as decimal(10,0))`... With that said, if you can control it, don't use `nvarchar` to store `int` or `decimal` data types.

Comment: The problem is right here "the amounts in both tables are nvarchar dataTypes". You should choose an appropriate datatype for the data being stored. Storing numbers as strings is bad idea. If you used the appropriate datatype this would be simple.

Comment: The fact that 4 of us have effectively made the same comment is quite telling. :)

Comment: @MarkKram i have updated question to show you the results. i would like the result to be '150'

Comment: I didnt create the database lol im just asked to create the report folks :)

Comment: Every time you store a number as a varchar, Satan drowns a kitten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x as varchar(32) = '653710000.01';

--note rounding error occurs
select CAST(CAST(@x As FLOAT) AS NVARCHAR(32));

--how to break this one?
select 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[.]%',REVERSE(@x)) = PATINDEX('%[123456789.]%',REVERSE(@x)) 
            THEN 
                   LEFT(@x, LEN(@X) - PATINDEX('%[.]%',REVERSE(@x))) 
            ELSE  

                CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[.]%',REVERSE(@x)) > 0 
                    THEN 
                        LEFT(@x, 1 + LEN(@X) - PATINDEX('%[123456789.]%',REVERSE(@x)))  
                    ELSE
                        @X
                    END
            END  ;
```

Comment: Mark this looks better than what I had. Lengthy but worth a try. Have not been able to break it. @Cato, voted up.

Comment: Ok thank you. Will give it a go and see. Thanks @asantaballa

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CAST(CAST(s.Gross As FLOAT) AS NVARCHAR(32))
```

But if you have control of  the table note that several comments on your question are saying that would be better to store as numeric. And not that this takes advantage of making it numeric to work with. So if you can, consider changing the type on the table and I agree with the others, the problem just goes away.

Comment: Yes i understand all the comments about the type. But i was only asked to create the report, I didn't create the actual DB. Your answer worked for me though, thanks a lot! much appreciated.

Comment: goes wrong at surprisingly low numbers, e.g. DECLARE @x as varchar(50) = '65376.010';
select CAST(CAST(@x As FLOAT) AS NVARCHAR(32));

Comment: hmm...that might be lack of precision on FLOAT. Let me try a couple of things and will get back

Comment: sorry, not meaning to pick fault, see if you can break mine, it's bound to go disastrously wong somewhere

Comment: Mark, not had any luck. If there's any way you can set Cato's answer as the correct one would do so. Not sure why SQL Server is doing this. The number are small enough to represent accurately in FLOAT, and when the type it FLOAT displays well. But just the conversion to VARCHAR appears to be ruder in rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend converting to a `float`, because that can have unintended consequences because `float` is not an exact representation.  You can just use string operations.  For instance:

```
select (case when s.gross like '%.%'
             then replace(rtrim(replace(s.gross, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
             else s.gross
        end)
```

For instance, try running [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3b2f3bf4887cd4930004e114bf25380).

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . I fixed the typo.  Here is the DB Fiddle of it working:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60f8b2af9848cd16d28ff8b5cd6a9a78.